# 'Anti-recursive' aggregation of shared quantity pools

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I have a structure like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Tree 
(
    Item VARCHAR(6),
    TreePosition VARCHAR(7),
    RequiredPerParentQty FLOAT,
    ExistingQty FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO #Tree 
VALUES
    ('item0', '0', 2, 1),
    ('item1', '0.0', 2, 2),
    ('item2', '0.1', 3, 1),
    ('item3', '0.1.0', 1, 2),
    ('item4', '0.2', 2, 0),
    ('item5', '0.2.0', 1, 2),
    ('item6', '0.2.1', 1, 3),
    ('item7', '0.3', 2, 0),
    ('item8', '0.3.0', 1, 1),
    ('item9', '0.3.0.0', 1, 1),
    ('item6', '0.3.0.1', 3, 3),
    ('item10', '0.3.1', 1, 1),
    ('item6', '0.3.2', 1, 3)
```

And I need an output that tallies not only the existing quantities according to each item, to ensure there is enough to satisfy every kind within each subtree and ultimately `item0`, but also to consider the pools of quantities of component items for generating missing quantities.

The output to the provided table would be something like:

| Item | Required | Supplied |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item0 | 2 | 1 |
| item1 | 2 | 2 |
| item2 | 3 | 3 |
| item4 | 2 | 2 |
| item7 | 2 | 1 |
| item8 | 1 | 2 |

I feel like this would be trivial in a procedural language, but I can't figure out what it looks like declaratively. It definitely seems like it should be something well understood, so I'm hoping it is.

Let me know if you have any familiarity or suggestions for what might work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what you ment with: "*And I need an output that tallies not only the existing quantities according to each item, to ensure there is enough to satisfy every kind within each subtree*" and  I would seriously suggest not having a TreePosition like a string (just add a parent ID or whatever), but I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(Item), 
    SUM(RequiredPerParentQty) AS RequiredPerParentQty,
    SUM(ExistingQty) AS ExistingQty 
FROM #Tree 
GROUP BY Item 
ORDER BY Item
```

You can leave out the `ORDER BY` since it doesn't do anything for the data except "prettify" it.

But what you're asking is a "distinct" item "grouped by" that same item and just summarize the values in there

Comment: Sorry I was having trouble explaining it. I'll try to get some better test data that emphasizes the specific edge cases that need to be accounted for.
But basically if an item is missing quantities, it can look to its children to see if there's enough to fill what's missing; what remains from those children can be used in the case of other items with missing quantities--but eventually those stores will run out, and any others remaining which need them will no longer have access and will be stuck with their existing quantities only.

Comment: You can see `item8` has 2/1, which would give its parent `item7` enough for its 2/2, but `item7` itself also uses `item6`, and there isn't enough potential to satisfy both.

Comment: Especially with this case you're describing you'll need a different way of defining your parent-child relation; string based is going to take a lot of CPU

Comment: In any case, that's where my data starts.

Comment: That said, one of my first steps is to add the parent strings to each item, so only performing one string operation per record; the rest is just comparison.